# Django 401 (Unauthorized) On making PUT request with axios. But working with Postman

Tags: reactjs, django, axios

I'm trying to update the User in Django from react side.
The same function has worked on testing through Postman. But when I try to make a request using Axios in react.js Django doesn't accept it. and throw 401 error.

```
 [23/Feb/2022 02:32:11] "PUT /api/v1/accounts/user-profile-update/ HTTP/1.1" 401 58
```

On the postman, I'm using Bearer Token for authorization. And the same token I'm passing in headers config.

```
    // Related Action Code
    const userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'))

    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${userData.token}`
    }
    const { data } = await axios.put(
        `/api/v1/accounts/user-profile-update/`,
        config
    )
```

EDIT :
Related API VIEW:

```
@api_view(['PUT'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def updateUserProfile(request):
    data = request.data
    user = request.user
    serializer = UserSerializerWithToken(user, many=False)

    user.name = data['name']
    user.phoneNumber = data['phoneNumber']
    user.city = data['city']
    user.postalCode = data['postalCode']
    user.country = data['country']
    user.save()

    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Two different responses on Django server:
With Postman

```
[23/Feb/2022 02:14:16] "PUT /api/v1/accounts/user-profile-update/%0A HTTP/1.1" 200 1182
```

And with React frontend

```
[23/Feb/2022 02:32:11] "PUT /api/v1/accounts/user-profile-update/ HTTP/1.1" 401 58
```

Can anybody find out why this happening? And how to fix that problem.

> EDIT: Note: This problem only happens on PUT or PATCH requests and work with GET requests.
> I'm still unable to figure out why this is happening. If I use the
> same token and test my views with Postman they work absolutely fine
> but not with a react-redux setup.

Comment: @AnkitTiwari This is not fixing the issue, same thing happening

Comment: I think AUTHORIZATION should be json key like 'Authorization': `Bearer ${userData.token}`

Comment: Yes tried already @ankit suggested that before. But doesn't work

Comment: @WasifAli after checking the config.headers in console I get this `{Content-type: 'application/json', Authorization: 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2…TUifQ.wbSSCMWPk5CjSRqxj70rDd3hqP_uRBtgpIAw1gzaEhk'}
Authorization: "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoicmVmcmVzaCIsImV4cCI6MTY1OTM4Nzg0NSwiaWF0IjoxNjQ1DTYzODQ1LCJqdGkiOiI1MTcxNDk5YmQ0YjM0NjZiYWI4Yjg1MGYyN2QxODE1OSIsInVzZXJfaWQiOiI2NTYxMWJhMi1kMDY2LTQxOGQtYjBkZi1mMmM0M2Q4MmJhZTUifQ.wbSSCMWPk5CjSRqxj70rD93hqP_uRBtgpIAw1gzaEhk"
Content-type: "application/json"`

Comment: Please try this . 
       const headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${userData.token}`
    }
 const { data } = await axios.put(
        `/api/v1/accounts/profile/update/`,
{headers}
    )
It might help

Comment: Ok .Let me check

Comment: You are getting authorization multiple times!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242288/discussion-between-faisal-nazik-and-wasif-ali).

Answer (score 1):

You are passing headers as a second argument whereas in put() method, first argument is for url, second is for data/payload to be sent and the third is for headers. Use like this axios.put(‘url’, data, { headers});